# How to collect data from an image using python

Tags: python

I have some image files with lots of data. How to collect the data from the images and put them in an excel sheet using python code?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Python Image Library (PIL) to read the image file information.

Consider using one of the excel writing libraries found on this http://www.python-excel.org/ site.